# Asynchronous init.d script

Tags: server, minecraft, init.d

I'm wondering if it is possible for a startup script to run continuously in Ubuntu. What I have in mind is something like a Minecraft server script that is constantly running so that if the server crashes for some reason, I can run the command again and reboot it. So basically I would have the command to run my minecraft server in a while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding [this](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Ubuntu_startup_script) which answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this.  This answer is one I personally prefer.  It is a quick-and-dirty answer.  But from your question, I gather that's all you are looking for.

1 Create the script that does the thing you want in a loop.  For example:

```sh
while [ 1 ]; do
    echo `date` >> /some/file/somewhere
    sleep 1
done
```

2 Create a second script checks to see if the first script is running.  If not, run it:

```sh
VAR=`ps -ef |grep "name_of_script_1" |wc -l`
#VAR returns 1 if not running (because grep returns itself), 
#    2 if it is running.  
if [ "${VAR}" -eq "1" ]; then
    /run/script/1 &
fi
```

3 Run the second script in the cron on some interval, like every 5 mins.

```sh
*/5 * * * * root /run/script/2
```

So, every 5 mins, script2 checks to see if script 1 is running. If it's not running, it starts it up and tosses it into the background.

There are lots of articles on the internet to help with specific elements (running something in the cron, while/if syntax, putting program into background, etc.  But this should get you close to what you are looking for.